# use lapply to manipulate a list of list

Tags: r

I have a list of 20 sub-lists named `pval`, each sub-list `pval[[i]]` contains several columns. I want to add a new column `pval[[i]]$class`  to mark whether the element of vector `causal_snp` appears in the column `X4` of each sub-list, if yes, mark 1 in the new column, else 0.

```
for (i in 1:20){
  pval[[i]]$class = ifelse(pval[[i]]$X4 %in% causal_snp, 1, 0)
  pval[[i]]$class = as.factor(pval[[i]]$classe)
}
```

The loop above works well, but I'd like use the function lapply instead of for loop, here is what I've tried, but the output contains only the new column for each sub-list:

```
pval_bis <- lapply(pval, function(x) x$classe=ifelse(x$X4 %in% causal_snp, 1, 0))
```

What can I modify in lapply function to keep all my columns in sub-list and add the new column in each sub-list? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide data for a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `lapply`, create the column with `transform`

```
lapply(pval, transform, classe = as.integer(X4 %in% causal_snp))
```

---

In the OP's code, after the assignment, we need to return `x`

```
 lapply(pval, function(x) {x$classe=ifelse(x$X4 %in% causal_snp, 1, 0);x})
```